# "InstalledAppFlow.run_local_server()" systematically add a slash to the end of the redirect URL

Tags: python, google-oauth

Here is the code:

```
from typing import List
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

PATH_FILE_SECRETS: str = secrets.json'
SCOPES: List[str] = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
LOCAL_REDIRECT_SERVER_DOMAIN='thermotest.ddns.net'
LOCAL_REDIRECT_SERVER_PORT=80

flow: InstalledAppFlow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(PATH_FILE_SECRETS, SCOPES)

credentials = flow.run_local_server(LOCAL_REDIRECT_SERVER_DOMAIN, LOCAL_REDIRECT_SERVER_PORT)
```

I use `google-auth-oauthlib` version `0.2.0` (the [last version](https://pypi.org/project/google-auth-oauthlib/)).

And, I have registered this redirect URL:

```
http://thermotest.ddns.net:80
```

The problem is that the method "`run_local_server`" generates a URL that ends with a slash :

```
 ...&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fthermotest.ddns.net%3A80%2F...
```

Which, once decoded, gives the value:

```
 http://thermotest.ddns.net:80/
```

Thus, Google complains that:

> The redirect URI in the request, http://thermotest.ddns.net:80/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

This is normal because "`http://thermotest.ddns.net:80/`" is not **strictly identical** to "`http://thermotest.ddns.net:80`".

If I modify the URL by removing the last "`%2F`" (I remove the last slash), then it's OK.

My question is: why does "`run_local_server`" systematically add a slash to the end of the redirect URL ? Can I tell the method not to do so ?

Comment: can you simply add `http://thermotest.ddns.net:80/` to your list of redirect URIs?

Comment: I tried. But it is not possible. Google says that the URL cannot end with a /... Thus I think that there is a bug in their API (as incredible as it seems).

Comment: We encountered a similar issue. We randomly tried to append the slash to our uri couple of days later and it magically worked. We have not found a way to reproduce the issue, but one thing to try out would be to clear the browser caches. Other than that it is either contacting the google support or playing the waiting game.

See also https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/24543#issuecomment-803943873

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else looking for the answer, this is a flag that can be passed to disable automatically adding a trailing slash

`credentials = flow.run_local_server(...)`

needs this argument passed into it:

`credentials = flow.run_local_server(redirect_uri_trailing_slash=False)`